# How to evaluate the fate (dropped, added or persisted) of species in consecutive years in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, reshape

> Blockquote

I have several time-series of varying length in a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

I want to see if a species dropped or added or persisted from one year to the other year. The output can be like this:
[image]

Comment: It's easyer if you provide a reproductible code .. what have you tried till now ? and what is the use of time_ID if it's always 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, here is the code that I used previously but it was only taking first and last year
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(year %in% range(year)) %>%
  group_by(spe, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(fate = case_when(n() == 2 ~ 'persist', 
                             any(year != max(.$year)) ~ 'dropped', 
                             any(year != min(.$year)) ~ 'added')) %>%
  ungroup

Comment: time_ID is actually the time-series ID. I have several of these so for each of the time-series I want to calculate this.

Comment: I don't know if this makes any sense to me Gull. Why isn't row 2 added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df2 <- df |>
  mutate(alive = 1) |>
  group_by(time_ID, species) |>
  complete(Year = min(df$Year):max(df$Year), fill = list(alive = 0)) |> 
  mutate(state = case_when(!alive & !cumsum(alive) ~ "unborn",
                            alive & cumsum(alive) == 1 ~ "new",
                            alive & cumsum(alive) > 1 ~ "old",
                            TRUE ~ "dead")) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
   time_ID species  Year alive state 
     <int> <chr>   <int> <dbl> <chr> 
 1       1 A        2000     1 new   
 2       1 A        2001     1 old   
 3       1 A        2002     0 dead  
 4       1 B        2000     1 new   
 5       1 B        2001     0 dead  
 6       1 B        2002     0 dead  
 7       1 C        2000     1 new   
 8       1 C        2001     1 old   
 9       1 C        2002     1 old   
10       1 D        2000     0 unborn
11       1 D        2001     0 unborn
12       1 D        2002     1 new   
13       1 E        2000     0 unborn
14       1 E        2001     0 unborn
15       1 E        2002     1 new
```

We could then do something like:

```
df2 |> pivot_wider(id_cols = c(time_ID, species), names_from = Year, values_from = state)
```

To create:

```
  time_ID species `2000` `2001` `2002`
    <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1       1 A       new    old    dead  
2       1 B       new    dead   dead  
3       1 C       new    old    old   
4       1 D       unborn unborn new   
5       1 E       unborn unborn new
```

Comment: feel free to ask any questions if there's any confusion or you want things to be different!